# nestjs Post cannot receive array of multiple json `this.build(...).save is not a function`

Tags: node.js, json, nestjs

I am trying to Post array of json objects to nestjs @Post and it doesnt accept it.

my controller

```
@Post()
async create(@Res() res, @Body() data: any) {
    if (!data || (data && Object.keys(data).length === 0)) {
        throw new HttpException("Empty Body ", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    let result: any = await this.Service.creat(data);

    if (!result.success) {
        throw new HttpException(result.message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(result);
}
```

my service

```
constructor(
        @Inject('DATA_REPOSITORY')
        private dataRepository: typeof Vols
    ) { }
  public async creat(data: any): Promise<object> {
    let newData: any;
    newData = await this.dataRepository.create<data>(data);
return newData;
}
```

Vols : -> is just my Model of columns

```
id: number;
name:string


 `[ 
    { id:1 name:'test2' }, 
    { id:2, name:'test' }
```

]`

Comment: Is your `creat` function complete? You don't have `return newData`, so result would be undefined.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera yes I just updated my answer, I had return. i missed it when I was copying my code. thank you

Comment: @AlbertoRivera I just get an error when data is coming in for POST TypeError: this.build(...).save is not a function

Comment: You may also want to post the code for your dataRepository.create

Comment: @AlbertoRivera added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create is for a single use, try bulkSave

```
await this.dataRepository.buldSave<data>(data)
```